# Bundle version in iOS and Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to retrieve the short version and bundle version of my application in phonegap. Any ideas how can I do it?

Using `device.version` from phonegap api would return the version number of the device OS.

Comment: The version number of your application itself. The one you set on xcode.

Comment: ok this may help u have a look at this  http://pervasivecode.blogspot.in/2012/04/get-version-number-of-live-app-on-app.html

Comment: http://pervasivecode.blogspot.in/2012/04/get-version-number-of-live-app-on-app.html have a look at this

Comment: okay. but what if i haven't uploaded my application yet. what apple id should i use?

Comment: come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap chat room and ask some one there u might get help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550705/how-to-get-the-application-version-and-build-in-an-ios-phonegap-application/14713364#14713364