# How to get app version number in iOS PhoneGap app?

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to show my *app version* on my iPhone app home screen.I am building an iPhone app using *Sencha touch* through *PhoneGap*. Whenever I build an app using PhoneGap on my Mac machine I manually increment a version and build number.Now I want to take this updated version number and want to show it on home screen.Is there any way from PhoneGap or Sencha Touch to do this ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550705/how-to-get-the-application-version-and-build-in-an-ios-phonegap-application

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a string that is your updated version number somewhere in the html or through javascript. If someone is using the newest version then it will only show this string since it has been updated. It does require remembering to change it with each build. Anyone on an older version would only have an older string. Serves the same purpose in the end.